# Получить PID дочерних потоков в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

**Вступление**:
Есть консольное приложение (JRE1.6 !!!), в нем создается конфигурация для будующих дочерних потоков, в нем можно запускать дочерние потоки и (требуется реализовать) останавливать дочерние потоки.
 1. Главный поток main запускает дочерние потоки и завершается;
 2. Дочерние потоки работают в бесконечном цикле;
 3. Дочерние потоки не могут создать потоки;

---

Подскажите правильно ли я думаю:
Останавливать дочерние потоки из главного потока main с помощью команды

```
String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "killall " + PID };
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( cmd );
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Но для данного метода надо знать pid дочернего процесса.

**Вопрос**:
Как мне получить pid дочернего процесса?

**П.С.**
Смог найти информацию только о том как получить PID родительского процесса:

```
String proccessName = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
Long pid = Long.parseLong( proccessName.split( "@" )[0] );
```

Comment: поясни, что ты понимаешь под понятием `Главный поток main запускает дочерние потоки`. Он запускает их при помощи некоего аналога `Thread.start()` или же идёт запуск стороннего приложения через систему?

Comment: В цикле Thread.start()

Comment: Во-первых, надо научиться различать процессы и потоки. Во-вторых, вызов killall из java-программы - это такой жуткий костыль, что хочется с криком отпрыгнуть. В-третьих, поток должен сам управлять своим жизненным циклом, из другого потока его останавливать нельзя. Надо отправить всем порождённым потокам сигнал о необходимости завершить работу, а в потоках его обработать.

Comment: 1) Я учусь различать потоки от процессов. 2) Я вроде бы написал "Подскажите правильно ли я думаю:", название этого как "жуткий костыль" вполне достаточно, прыгать не надо, можете ведь сломать себе что нибудь....))) 3) В случае возникновения каких-либо ошибок в потоке он будет завершаться и кидать SNMP трап в Zabbix, но должен быть еще функционал остановки конкретного потока из Main. 4) Зачем всем порожденным потокам отправлять сообщение о завершении??? каждый дочерний поток выполняет в цикле какое - то свое действие, их всех нельзя останавливать ради одного.